# Numpy rounding issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can someone explain to me why is numpy round acting strange with this exact number rounding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': [121921117.714999988675115, 445, 22]})
df = np.round(df['c'], 8)

Result:
121921117.71499997
445.0
22.0

Expected:
121921117.71499999
445.0
22.0
```

It's obvious that the first number is not rounded well, any ideas?

EDIT:
Since I'm focused here on the precision, not so much on the performance, I've used python round function to solve this problem:

```
df.applymap(round, ndigits=8)
```

Comment: always tag python questions with the generic [python] tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the small print [2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) in the documentation of `round` aka `around`.
The short answer is that `round` "uses a fast but sometimes inexact algorithm" and to use `format_float_positional` if you want to see
the correct result.

[image]

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'c': [121921117.714999988675115, 445, 22]})
>>> df["c"][0]
121921117.71499999
>>> round(df["c"][0],8)
121921117.71499997
>>> np.format_float_positional(df["c"][0],8)
'121921117.71499999'
```

Comment: Great, thanks for explaining all of this. I'm focused here on the precision, not so much on the performance, so I've used this function (edited the original post also):
df.applymap(round, ndigits=decimals)