# Round on DataFrames transform perfect number in decimals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am currently working with pandas version 2.2.0 and I have the following issue when rounding my DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"value": [26586491.0]}).round(15)["value"].iloc[0]
[2]: 26586490.999999996
```

This is annoying because there might be situations where we want to compare the exact value. Using numpy directly gives similar issues.
Any idea what is wrong here ? I guess the problem comes from how pandas stores floats but is there a way to avoid such behavior ?

Comment: "Any idea what is going wrong here ?" [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6394617)

Comment: If you want to compare floating point numbers, use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) (or the numpy equivalent)

Comment: If you need exact decimals, look into the python decimal package, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558299/6394617) answer

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
My question was more about why does round() transform my value ? Pandas can store the integer (if I remove the round function, the output is ok) so why does it change it in the end ?
This column can serve as a foreign key for other tables so this issue might break joins in the future.

Comment: So this is a NumPy issue, since pandas is using NumPy to do the math. You can reproduce this with simply `np.round(26586491.0, 15)`  According to the NumPy [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round.html) "np.round uses a fast but sometimes inexact algorithm to round floating-point datatypes."  I suggest that you don't use floats as keys for joins if you plan to manipulate those floats in some of the tables (e.g. rounding).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73239561/6394617)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. This seems indeed a limitation of the round function. Unfortunately, my problem comes here from the output of the read_sas that gives a similar issues for other variables so it is hard to specify the type in a generic solution. I will look for a turnaround. Thank you again for your answers!